# Passing values from JSP to Controller using f:checkbox

Tags: java, json, spring, checkbox

I have an implementation where when user click on checkbox , a json gets associated as value of checkbox and that value is passed to my bean class.
And In the method invoked, the String is then parsed into JSON object.
When I select two checkbox, it works perfectly fine. But if I select one checkbox, then it gives me error.

Here is my Checkbox Bean class -

```
private ArrayList<String> Ancillary=new ArrayList<String>()  ;


public ArrayList<String> getAncillary() {
    for(int i=0;i<Ancillary.size();i++){
    System.out.println(i+"Object:" +Ancillary.get(i)+"\n\n\n");
    }
    return Ancillary;
}

public void setAncillary(ArrayList<String> ancillary) {
    Ancillary = ancillary;
}
```

Here is my method where I print value of a Particular key in JSON.

```
public Event updatePax(RequestContext context) throws Exception {
    ExtrasMenu extrasMenu = (ExtrasMenu) context.getConversationScope().get(ScopeKeys.EXTRASMENU);
    System.out.println("As a string:"+extrasMenu.getAncillary().toString());
    JSONObject json=new JSONObject(extrasMenu.getAncillary().get(0));
    System.out.println(json.get("firstName"));
   }
```

And here is the Output-

If only one checkbox is selected -

```
0Object:{"firstName":"TIMOTHY"
1Object:"lastName":"WALKER"
2Object:"price":100}
```

If two or more checkboxes are selected -

```
0Object:{"firstName":"TIMOTHY","lastname":"WALKER","price":"50"}
1Object:{"firstName":"ANNE","lastname":"WALKER","price":"150"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, I couldnt figure out why ArrayList is taking input like this, 
I created a special case when User selects one check box. I will take the ArrayList and convert it to a String using toString. 
So, the output of toString will be like -

```
{"firstName":"TIMOTHY","lastname":"WALKER","price":"50"}
```

Now I used a try catch block to create JSON object out of the string I get from toString.

```
            JSONObject json=null;
            try{
            json=new JSONObject(extrasMenu.getAncillary().get(i));
        }
        catch(org.json.JSONException e){
                int len=extrasMenu.getAncillary().toString().length();
                json=new JSONObject(extrasMenu.getAncillary().toString());
        }
```

So If it throws an error, the full list as a string will be used to create JSON object. 
Although It is working fine, Still I am not very sure about Why ArrayList is working like this !